# Webscraping - check for new entries

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner python learner and this is my first try and my own webscraping script.

Basically the script checks the newest entries on a Belgian real-estate site and shows me the entries on the page (sorted by newest). It then adds those href tags to a list (url_list).

The url_list then gets checked with the updated_list to see if they are the same.

- If they are the same, nothing happens (no new entries).
- If they are not the same and the updated_list was empty, it was the first time the program ran so nothing happens.
- If the updated list was not empty and it does not match the url_list and email is send to me with the first 5 urls from the list.

Afterwards the updated_list is set to the url_list in preperation of the next check and my url_list is cleared so it can get filled again from the next search that happens when the sleep timer ends.

However, when I'm running this script I'm always getting the new entry and an e-mail is send to me (except for the first time the program runs). I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

**Functions:**

```
import time
import os
import smtplib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

# functions

def immoWebParser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/zoeken/huis/te-koop?countries=BE&orderBy=newest')
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

    web_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    for house in web_soup.find_all('article'):

        link = house.find(
            'a', class_='card__title-link')['href']
        url_list.append(link)

        # print(link) #dev check

        # print() #dev check

    driver.close()

def sendEmail():

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()

        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

        subject = 'New entries on ImmoWeb'
        body = "\r\n".join(updated_list[:5])

        msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'email adress here', msg)
```

**script:**

```
url_list = []
updated_list = []
timer_count = 20
while True:

    print('Checking new houses')
    immoWebParser()

    """ If statement that checks if there are new entries by comparing two lists """
    if updated_list == url_list:
        print('There are no new entries')

    else:
        print('There are new entries')
        if updated_list == []:
            print('First time the program ran, nothing to report')
        else:
            print('SENDING EMAIL PLEASE CHECK')
            sendEmail()
    updated_list = url_list
    url_list = []
    print(len(url_list))  # Dev test to see if the if/else works correctly
    print(len(updated_list))  # Dev test to see if the if/else works correctly
    print('website checked, time for a ' + str(timer_count) + ' second nap')
    time.sleep(timer_count)
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback and a push in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok. You are getting new links every time.
Pay attention to the `searchId` part:

```
https://www.immoweb.be/nl/zoekertje/huis/te-koop/heusy/4802/9019767?searchId=5f9ebde4c0405
```

I am not sure if you need it. If not, you can trim it before adding to the list.

Comment: Thank you @Sergey Inshev ! So if I understand correctly, the scraped url changes every time a new scrape is being started? So to summarise I need to cut off the part behind the ? In the url because that searchid is unique every time the script opens the webpage?